# How to create an image mask and render a texture to it in cocos2d

Tags: opengl-es, cocos2d-iphone, textures, image-masking

I am writing a game in cocos2d v3 which has platforms whose shapes can be manipulated by the user. I know every point along the edge of the platform, and want to render a texture just within the shape of the platform so it will appear solid. 
I know I need to use OpenGl, or a CCrender texture, but I am a complete beginner to it and can only articulate my ideas in words, not in code. I don't know if any of these would work. Please help me by giving an example of what I should do. 
Here are my ideas:

[1] - To color the shape white, and put a ccrednertexture under it and render the texture to the render texture - then use a blend function to only allow what is under the white on the render texture to show through.

[2] To use the vertexes around the shape to do something like this:

```
CCRenderBuffer buffer = [renderer enqueueTriangles:2 andVertexes:4 withState:_lightRenderState globalSortOrder:0];
                CCRenderBufferSetVertex(buffer, 0, LightVertex(projection, GLKVector2Make(pos.x - radius, pos.y - radius), GLKVector2Make(0, 0), color4));
                CCRenderBufferSetVertex(buffer, 1, LightVertex(projection, GLKVector2Make(pos.x - radius, pos.y + radius), GLKVector2Make(0, 1), color4));
                CCRenderBufferSetVertex(buffer, 2, LightVertex(projection, GLKVector2Make(pos.x + radius, pos.y + radius), GLKVector2Make(1, 1), color4));
                CCRenderBufferSetVertex(buffer, 3, LightVertex(projection, GLKVector2Make(pos.x + radius, pos.y - radius), GLKVector2Make(1, 0), color4));
                CCRenderBufferSetTriangle(buffer, 0, 0, 1, 2);
                CCRenderBufferSetTriangle(buffer, 1, 0, 2, 3);
```

Comment: Are you simply talking about allowing users to color over the platforms?

Comment: No, they can reshape it by dragging around its vertexes, and I want to render a texture inside the shape created by the different vertexes.